# Project won't run as maven integration-test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, integration-testing

I have created Maven java project to use Selenium and am using the following example:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/examples/using-with-surefire.html

(The code is edited slightly):

```
package Test.SeleniumTest;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

public class SeleniumExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    protected DefaultSelenium createSeleniumClient(String url) throws Exception 
    {
        return new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", url);
    }

    public void testSomethingSimple() throws Exception 
    {

        DefaultSelenium selenium = createSeleniumClient("http://www.google.com");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("http://localhost:8081/SWReconciliation/");      

        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

The java file will run fine as JUnit test but when I try to run them as integration-test tests, I get the following error:

```
16:36:36.051 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
16:36:57.801 ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox refused shutdown while preparing a profile
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:367)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:412)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.launchRemoteSession(FirefoxLauncher.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:381)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:810)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:151)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher$FileLockRemainedException: Lock file still present! C:\Users\MC44948\AppData\Local\Temp\customProfileDir1bd92674dfc04bb792f93d02c2cd3a3c\parent.lock
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFileLockToGoAway(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:318)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:365)
    ... 20 more
16:36:57.855 INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 21.908 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

I have used the following and still this error occurs. Can anyone help me as to why this is happening?

Comment: What version of firefox do you have?

Comment: It is complaining that some lock file is still present. Make sure that firefox is correctly closed, delete the lock and try again. Make also sure that other selenium tests you might have in your suite cleanup everything

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?